# Looking for a more efficient way to set and alter sequential Backbone model attributes

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

Using Backbone.js, I've created a `Products` collection made up of `Product` models.  Each `Product` model contains an `orderIndex` attribute.  The collection is using this `orderIndex` attribute as its comparator.

During my app's operation, I need to change the `orderIndex` value for one of the products in the collection.  When I do this, I also need to adjust the `orderIndex` for the other models in the collection so that they still remain in sequential order.  As an example, if I start with four models:

```
A -> orderIndex = 0
B -> orderIndex = 1
C -> orderIndex = 2
D -> orderIndex = 3
```

And then I change the `orderIndex` of B to 2, I would then also want C to change to 1, so that B and C switch places when `sort()` is called on the collection:

```
A -> orderIndex = 0
B -> orderIndex = 2
C -> orderIndex = 1
D -> orderIndex = 3
```

Another example using the original setup would be if I changed orderIndex of A to 3, then I would also need B to change to 0, C to change to 1, and D to change to 2, resulting in:

```
A -> orderIndex = 3
B -> orderIndex = 0
C -> orderIndex = 1
D -> orderIndex = 2
```

I've written a function to handle this, but I feel like I'm overlooking a more efficient way to do this using more built in underscore or js functions.  Here's the function I'm using now:

```
adjustModelOrderIndex: function(model, newIndex){
    var currentOrderIndex = model.get("orderIndex");
    var newOrderIndex = newIndex;

    model.set({orderIndex: newOrderIndex});

    _.each(_.without(this.models, model), function(model){
        if(currentOrderIndex > newOrderIndex){
            if(model.get("orderIndex") >= newOrderIndex && model.get("orderIndex") <= currentOrderIndex){
                model.set({orderIndex: model.get("orderIndex") + 1});
            }
        }
        else{
            if(model.get("orderIndex") <= newOrderIndex && model.get("orderIndex") >= currentOrderIndex){
                model.set({orderIndex: model.get("orderIndex") - 1});
            }
        }
    }, this);

}
```

This function lives in my collection, and the arguments represent the model that is being changed, as well as the value that its `orderIndex` attribute is going to be changed to.

Can someone recommend a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually find plain old [`Array.prototype.splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) on the [raw array of models](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-models) to be of great help in this kind of situation. You can then use the natural order of the array to update your `orderIndex` attributes :

```
var OrderedCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    comparator: 'orderIndex',

    adjustModelOrderIndex: function(model, newIndex) {
        var currentOrderIndex = model.get("orderIndex");            
        if (newIndex === currentOrderIndex) return;

        // remove the model from the array
        this.models.splice(currentOrderIndex, 1);

        // reinject it at its new position
        this.models.splice(newIndex, 0, model);

        // update orderIndex
        this.each(function(model, ix) {
            model.set('orderIndex', ix);
        });

        // order changed, let's trigger a sort event
        // or use this.sort() if you prefer
        this.trigger('sort', this);
    }
});
```

Sample usage:

```
var c = new OrderedCollection([
    {id: 'D', orderIndex: 3},
    {id: 'C', orderIndex: 2},
    {id: 'B', orderIndex: 1},
    {id: 'A', orderIndex: 0}
]);
// ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
c.on('sort', function() {
    console.log(c.pluck('id'));
});

c.adjustModelOrderIndex(c.get('B'), 0); //  ["B", "A", "C", "D"]
c.adjustModelOrderIndex(c.get('B'), 1); //  ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
c.adjustModelOrderIndex(c.get('B'), 2); //  ["A", "C", "B", "D"]
c.adjustModelOrderIndex(c.get('A'), 3); //  ["C", "B", "D", "A"]
```

And a demo to play with http://jsfiddle.net/F6XSC/1/